# How to save VSE from crashing in render process?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, cache

I'm trying to render a video (duration - 10 minutes, + put music on top. In general, the render should be simple), but Blender cannot finish the render because it crash. I upgraded boosted 'Memory Cache Limit', it didn't help.

Can using 'Use Disk Cache' help to save video rendring from crashing?

[image]

Comment: It’s “crash”ing, not “crush”ing. I recommend running blender from the command line and watching for errors as it exits.

Comment: I don't think that "Use disk cache" or increasing the Memory Cache Limit will do any good to the render, certainly if the crash is caused by a shortage of memory. Next to what ZargulTheWizard already suggested, you can check your memory usage (in Windows with Task Manager). You can also try to render to PNG and check if any frames are rendered (and where the bottleneck is).